# How can I select which genetic operators configuration for a permutation problem and why?

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithms

I am try to solve a combinatory problem using genetic algorithms and the [GA](https://luca-scr.github.io/GA/index.html) package in R.

Essentially my problem statement is the following:

Given a fitness function $f(X)$, where $X$ is a division of $N$ objects in $K$ groups, what is the division of N objects in K groups $X'$ such that $f(X') = max$?

I coded the problem into a permutation problem (which is one of the 3 frameworks available in the GA package), however, my question is now, how can I select which crossover, selection and mutation genetic operators to use?

So far I've been using the defaults:

- ga_lrSelection()
- gaperm_cxCrossover()
- gaperm_simMutation()

But I see from the [documentation](https://luca-scr.github.io/GA/reference/index.html) that there are a lot of other options. I cannot possibly try all the combinations, is there a way of deciding which of the available genetic operators is best suited to my particular problem at hand?

Comment: I feel your pain here terribly and also wish someone could help answer this question. I understand the implications of choosing different mutation operators... e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/genetic_algorithms/genetic_algorithms_mutation.htm ...but I don't know what types of mutations the operators in the GA package correspond to.